# Prove an inequality concerning $\ln$ function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality

For any real number $p \in (0,1)$, $\delta \in (0,1)$ and $p+\delta <1$, prove the following inequality:
$$(p+\delta)\ln \frac {p+\delta}{p} +(1-p-\delta)\ln \frac {1-p-\delta}{1-p} \ge 2\delta^2$$

I have tried some appoximation on $\ln$ function such as $\ln(1+x) \le x$ and $\ln(1+x)\ge x-x^2/2$ but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint.

We need to prove that $f(\delta)\geq0,$ where
$$f(\delta)=(p+\delta)\ln \frac {p+\delta}{p} +(1-p-\delta)\ln \frac {1-p-\delta}{1-p}- 2\delta^2.$$
But by C-S $$f''(\delta)=\left(\ln\frac{p+\delta}{p}-\ln\frac{1-p-\delta}{1-p}-4\delta\right)'=$$
$$=\frac{1}{p+\delta}+\frac{1}{1-p-\delta}-4\geq\frac{(1+1)^2}{p+\delta+1-p-\delta}-4=0$$ and
$$\lim\limits_{\delta\rightarrow0^+} f'(\delta)=\lim\limits_{\delta\rightarrow0^+} f(\delta)=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Oh! Using Taylor expansion conclude the proof. Thanks!

Comment: @zbh2047  You are welcome!